# mapping through items in array node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

So I have an array where it stores the users language, like so:

```
let language = []
    
     var Lang = "it"
     language.push(Lang)
```

and I do this multiple times with different languages.

I basically want to go through the array, and check:

The array would look like this:

```
language = ["en", "it", "es"]
```

then I want to check all of the values in the array, and if none of them are `en`, then log.

```
if (Lang != "en") {
   console.log("no en")
}
```

I think I have to use mapping, I could be wrong. I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [`includes`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp):

```js
let language = ["en", "it", "es"];
if (language.includes("en"))
  console.log("have it");
```